# Update array in model

Tags: laravel

my function updates the **Prestamo** model but not in the **Presocio** model
Any idea how to perform the update to the Presocio model.
Using laravel.

```php
public function update(PrestamoRequest $request, $id)
{
    $prestamo           = Prestamo::findOrFail($id);
    $prestamo->socio_id = $request->socio_id;
    $prestamo->monto    = $request->monto;
    $prestamo->cuotas   = $request->cuotas;
    $prestamo->alias    = $request->alias;
    $prestamo->estado   = $request->estado;
    $prestamo->update();
    $idprestamo = $prestamo->id;

    if (count($request->ncuota) > 0) {
        foreach ($request->ncuota as $item => $v) {
            $presocio = Presocio::findOrFail($id);
            $presocio->fill([
                'prestamo_id' => $idprestamo,
                'ncuota'      => $request->ncuota[$item],
                'montopag'    => $request->montopag[$item],
                'fechapag'    => $request->fechapag[$item],
                'estadopag'   => $request->estadopag[$item]
            ])->update();
        }
        toast('Pago Programados Editado', 'success');
        return redirect('prestamo');
    }
}
```

suggestions please.

Comment: Please try to be more specific in you question. By the looks of it, you are trying to update a `Presocio` model with the same `$id` as the `Prestamo`. This looks incorrect.

Comment: Are you sure `count($request->ncuota) > 0`?

Comment: @thomas-van-der-veen I want to update my array, this in turn has a field related to another table. In other words, I have problems updating a detail master table.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#updates).

```php
$presocio->fill([
    'prestamo_id' => $idprestamo,
    'ncuota'      => $request->ncuota[$item],
    'montopag'    => $request->montopag[$item],
    'fechapag'    => $request->fechapag[$item],
    'estadopag'   => $request->estadopag[$item]
])->update();
```

Should be either

```php
$presocio->update([
    'prestamo_id' => $idprestamo,
    'ncuota'      => $request->ncuota[$item],
    'montopag'    => $request->montopag[$item],
    'fechapag'    => $request->fechapag[$item],
    'estadopag'   => $request->estadopag[$item]
]);
```

or

```php
$presocio->fill([
    'prestamo_id' => $idprestamo,
    'ncuota'      => $request->ncuota[$item],
    'montopag'    => $request->montopag[$item],
    'fechapag'    => $request->fechapag[$item],
    'estadopag'   => $request->estadopag[$item]
])->save();
```

Don't forget to set up the fillable attributes on your models as well.

Comment: tried but does not recognize the $id, I think it is because $id of the request associates it first with the model **Prestamo** and not in the model *Presocio*